# Low performance of pl/pgsql function

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a pl/pgsql function which is unstable. This is source:

```
DECLARE
l RECORD;
events_for_machine integer;
before_event "PRD".events_log;
machines_ids integer[];
island_controller RECORD;
before_order "PRD".events_log;
before_detail "PRD".events_log;
before_pallete "PRD".events_log;
before_operation "PRD".events_log;
timer timestamp;
timer2 timestamp;

BEGIN
machines_ids = string_to_array(machines_ids_g,',')::integer[];
for l in 
select m.*
from
    "PRD".machines m
    inner join
    unnest(machines_ids) n(id) on n.id = m.id
where
    m.start_work_date < begin_date_g
order by m.id
LOOP

SELECT * INTO island_controller FROM "STRUCT".island_machines WHERE machine_id=l.id;

RAISE NOTICE 'pobieram zdarzenie before dla maszyny %',l.id;

    SELECT * INTO before_event FROM "PRD".events_log WHERE plc_time < begin_date_g AND (((event_type_id IN (1,51) AND machine_id = island_controller.controller_id AND island_id = island_controller.island_id))
    OR (event_type_id IN (2000,2001) AND machine_id=l.id)) ORDER BY plc_time DESC LIMIT 1;

IF before_event.plc_time IS NOT NULL THEN    

RAISE NOTICE 'Getting info about first machine work time struct element';
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "PRD".events_log WHERE event_type_id = 113 AND machine_id=l.id AND plc_time < before_event.plc_time ORDER BY plc_time DESC LIMIT 1;
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "PRD".events_log WHERE event_type_id = 102 AND machine_id=l.id AND plc_time < before_event.plc_time ORDER BY plc_time DESC LIMIT 1;
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "PRD".events_log WHERE event_type_id = 111 AND machine_id=l.id AND plc_time < before_event.plc_time ORDER BY plc_time DESC LIMIT 1;
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "PRD".events_log WHERE event_type_id = 1010 AND machine_id=l.id AND plc_time < before_event.plc_time ORDER BY plc_time DESC LIMIT 1;
RETURN NEXT before_event;


END IF;
RAISE NOTICE 'generuje zdarzenia wlasciwe dla maszyny %',l.id;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "PRD".events_log WHERE 
            (event_type_id = ANY ('{1,51}'::integer[]) AND (machine_id=island_controller.controller_id AND island_id = island_controller.island_id) AND (plc_time BETWEEN begin_date_g AND end_date_g))
            OR (event_type_id = ANY ('{2000,2001,107}'::integer[]) AND machine_id=l.id AND (plc_time >= begin_date_g AND plc_time <= end_date_g))
            OR ((event_type_id = ANY ('{101,102,103,301,1010}'::integer[]) OR ((event_type_id >= 5000) AND (event_type_id <= 5999))) AND machine_id=l.id AND plc_time >= begin_date_g AND plc_time <= end_date_g) ORDER BY plc_time;

RAISE NOTICE 'koniec dla maszyny %',l.id;
END LOOP;

END;
```

Sometimes the function execution time is ~9 seconds, sometimes ~40 seconds for the same arguments. What does it depend?
What could be so inefficient?

Comment: Try posting your question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is more than one issue. I cannot to say, what is wrong, but probably it will be fast when it found necessary data in cache (postgresql, filesystem) and slow if not (and depends how many loops are there).

what is wrong:

useless join

```
machines_ids = string_to_array(machines_ids_g,',')::integer[];
for l in 
select m.*
from
    "PRD".machines m
    inner join
    unnest(machines_ids) n(id) on n.id = m.id
```

you can write

```
for l in
   select *
      from "PRD".machines m
     where m.id = ANY(string_to_array(machines_ids_g,',')::integer[])
loop
```

lot of repeated queries

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "PRD".events_log WHERE event_type_id = 113 AND machine_id=l.id AND plc_time < before_event.plc_time ORDER BY plc_time DESC LIMIT 1;
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "PRD".events_log WHERE event_type_id = 102 AND machine_id=l.id AND plc_time < before_event.plc_time ORDER BY plc_time DESC LIMIT 1;
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "PRD".events_log WHERE event_type_id = 111 AND machine_id=l.id AND plc_time < before_event.plc_time ORDER BY plc_time DESC LIMIT 1;
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM "PRD".events_log WHERE event_type_id = 1010 AND machine_id=l.id AND plc_time < before_event.plc_time ORDER BY plc_time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

it can be replaced by

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT *
                FROM "PRD".events
               WHERE (event_type_id, plc_time) = (SELECT max(plc_time), event_type_id
                                                     FROM "PRD".events
                                                    WHERE event_type_id IN (113,102,111,1010)
                                                    GROUP BY event_type_id);
```

probably composite index (event_type_id, plc_time) should help

Attention:

pattern:

```
FOR n IN SELECT
   SELECT .. WHERE ..=n
END FOR
```

can be slow when loops are too much and better to do with one query when it is possible